# Add a backlight effect in html (or css) when a video starts to play into a Wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video

I'm adding videos to a very specific website made with Wordpress. I have to control carefully each visual element and behaviour of this page wich is devoted to arts (And because of this, I must be very careful of resultns)

Well, I create a new Wordpress page and add the following code:

```
<video width="480" height="360" controls class="size-full wp-image-19 aligncenter">
<source src="http://URL_OF_MY VIDEO">
</video>
```

And everything goes on. The videos are hosted on the website server. I'm usign a 4:3 video.
But, when I select the fullsize option, the video wich is 4:3 shows in the screen midst without making the background be darker or black. Thus, we have a bad result consisting in a messy composition, ugly and far from my objective.

How could I add code to this html to archive this? Make the background darker while playing my video on fullscreen (if it's 4:3, it will left side spaces in a 16:9 screen)

EDIT:

I've tried to add this code to functions.php on the wordpress core.

```
//[myjavascript]
// Php function that executes javascript when a shortcode is called. Added to
//funcions.php
function myjavascript_func( $atts ){
return "<script>
document.getElementById("my_vid").addEventListener('play', lowLights, false);

function lowLights() {
this.removeEventListener('play', lowLights, false);
document.getElementById("videobox").style.backgroundColor="black";

</script>";
}
add_shortcode( 'myjavascript', 'myjavascript_func' );
```

But as a result, when I call this function via the shortcode [myjavascript], I obtain this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

I presume that could be because of the references to Id's.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You could wrap the element in an absolutely positioned element with a background color.

Comment: That's odd. Did you edit the html to include a wrapper elemenet and apply CSS to that wrapper element to ensure it covers the entire screen? That css would be something like { position : absolute; left : 0; top : 0; width : 100%; height : 100%; background : black; } although you would need to provide your own method of showing and hiding this when appropriate, maybe effecting the css display property using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<div id="videobox">
    <video id="my_vid">
        <source src="your-video-here.mp4">
        </source>
    </video>
</div>
```

then some JS:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("my_vid").addEventListener('play', lowLights, false);

function lowLights() {
    this.removeEventListener('play', lowLights, false);
    document.getElementById("videobox").style.backgroundColor="black";
}
</script>
```